# jQuery autocomplete ajax not working for autocorrection when wrong input is given

Tags: javascript, jquery, elasticsearch, flask, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a project similar to Google's search bar using Flask, Elasticsearch and jQuery that will automatically suggest based on input given and also automatically give correct suggestions when a wrong input is given. I've had success with the autosuggestion with correct spellings but when giving a wrong input, the correct suggestion data from Elasticsearch comes up in browser console but doesn't appear in the autocomplete drop-down. I inserted data into Elasticsearch using PySpark. I think the problem is related to the JS file but don't know if it's my JS file or the jquery-ui file. What am I doing wrong?

**JS:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    const $source = document.querySelector('#source');
    const $result = document.querySelector('#result');

    const typeHandler = function (e) {
        $result.innerHTML = e.target.value;
        console.log(e.target.value);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax_call",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'data': e.target.value },
            success: function (html) {
                var data = html.aggregations.auto.buckets
                var bucket = []

                $.each(data, (index, value) => {
                    bucket.push(value.key)
                });
                
                console.log(bucket)
                $("#source").autocomplete({
                    source: bucket
                });
            }
        });
    }
    $source.addEventListener('input', typeHandler)
});
```

**Correct Input:**

[image: Correct Input]

---

**Incorrect Input:**

[image: Incorrect Input]

---

**Correct data for Incorrect Input**

[image: Correct data for Incorrect Input]

Comment: Google search bar is based on Machine Learing Algorithm, That's understands your searching the suggest you another one based on how mcuh people search for same thing or the most similar to your searching. Auto Correction and Auto complete of google is not just based or ordered by name.

Comment: @Aggestor I said similar to Google, not same as Google. I just want the suggestions that appear in console to appear in the drop down even if my input is wrong.

Comment: @Varun are you logging the correct response and it's simply not showing in the autocomplete UI or is the screenshot above mocked?

Comment: @Joe The screenshots aren't mocked, they are snipped from the running Flask app. I want the correct response for my wrong input hence "autocorrection". The response I want is getting in the console as in the third screenshot but not showing in the drop down in second screenshot as you can see.

Comment: OK in that case I'd recommend some reading on the topic "typo tolerance" and "fuzzy queries". Here's a good start: https://medium.com/@taranjeet/elasticsearch-using-completion-suggester-to-build-autocomplete-e9c120cf6d87

Comment: @Joe Thanks and I'm now using Completion Suggester but since I don't have much experience with jQuery, I don't know how to get the result in the ajax call. Is there a way to make jQuery autocomplete work with typos meaning if I make a typo how can the suggested value be displayed on the frontend? Also we can't aggregate Completion Suggester results, Is there a workaround to get only the text?

Comment: I suspect the timing is off here. I would advise initializing the Autocomplete with a dynamic source.

Comment: @Twisty My data comes from Elasticsearch via Flask by a fuzzy query. My problem was just with JS file as I'm a total noob in that area. Your answer was the only one I needed. Thanks! There is just a minor mistake with brackets at the end. I submitted an edit on that but has yet to be approved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {
  const $source = $('#source');
  const $result = $('#result');

  $source.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax_call",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          'data': request.term
        },
        success: function(html) {
          var data = html.aggregations.auto.buckets;
          var bucket = [];

          $.each(data, (index, value) => {
            bucket.push(value.key);
          });

          console.log(bucket);
          response(bucket);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

See More:

- https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp
- https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: Thank you, thank you very much! This is just what I was looking for! BTW I also did a workaround by overriding the inbuilt autocomplete regex logic but that made the code look dirty. Anyways, you're a life saver! Thanks once again.